# How did the term "volume" come to be used for the control which adjusts loudness/intensity?

Tags: history

It's a term we're all familiar with, but how did it come to be chosen as the name of the control which makes an audio output louder or quieter?

Comment: I don't think that is an engineering term, and the question is not about electrical engineering theory or design. The question probably belongs in the English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Contact [this man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_McWhorter). He will tell you more than you will ever want to know. (And, I suspect, he will respond if you ask politely.)

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford English Dictionary gives this earliest cite from 1822:

[image]

It simply referred to "volume of sound", and the latter part got dropped.

The etymology of the noun "volume" from [this](https://www.etymonline.com/word/volume) source:

> 14c., "roll of parchment containing writing; a bound book," from Old French volume "scroll, book; work, volume; girth, size" (13c.) and directly from Latin volumen (genitive voluminis) "roll (of a manuscript); coil, wreath," literally "that which is rolled," from volvere "to turn around, roll," from PIE root *wel- (3) "to turn, revolve." Meaning "book forming part of a set" is 1520s in English, from that sense in French. Generalized sense of "bulk, mass, quantity" (1620s) developed from that of "bulk or size of a book" (1520s), again following the sense evolution in the French word.

Answer (score 0):

Energy density of sound or loudness level is the energy per unit **volume** of air.

The history of the term probably predates electromagnet speakers.